# Is there an easy way to print a few variables in KQL?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Sometimes I need to check what is inside my multiple variables. Is there an easy way to output smth like a few print statements?
Let's say I have:

```
let a = 1;
let b = 2;
let c = 3;
```

I need:

```
1
2
3
```

or

```
1 2 3
```

or even better

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `print` to print them all in single query. Is this what you mean?

```
let a = 1;
let b = 2;
let c = 3;
print a,b,c
```

[image]